Which ethical philosophy specifically addresses this type of moral dillema?
Sacrificing all of humanity to save one or two of your most loved ones, such as your parents, versus sacrificing your most loved one(s) to save all of humanity? Is there any philosophy (or philosopher) that explicitly argues against saving one's most loved family member(s)? And, is there any philosophy that advocates the opposite of this?

Useful web search term for related, though less drastic, conflict: "trolley problem".


Which ethical philosophy specifically addresses this type of moral dillema?

Almost every ethical philosophy will have an answer to (or at least an approach to reasoning through) this dilemma. Some might not even consider it a dilemma. As Weather Vane observes, utilitarianism has one answer. Egoism might have a different answer. Ethical philosophies drawing on religious premises might have different answers.

It is utilitarianism. Wikipedia says

utilitarian ideas encourage actions that lead to the greatest good for the greatest number

As for the opposite, saving one or two of your parents (and perhaps yourself, although the question doesn't say), is according to this site

moral myopia is the difficulty people sometimes have in clearly seeing ethical issues and ethical challenges.

And if you save one parent, sacrificing all others, the eyes are firmly shut.

Moral myopia or blindness. Is it because of kin selection theory? This question (my original) is interesting because whenever I ask this question to anyone who is utilitarian, they always save their parents. Can we say that this moral myopia happens because of kin selection theory?

The obvious advocate for saving the most amount of people in this case would be utilitarianism. You can postulate whether others would advocate for it too, like virtue ethics or deontological theories, which would depend on what you consider to be virtuous or your moral obligation (i.e. do you have a moral obligation to always save your parents? or do you have a moral obligation to save the greatest amount of people?)
An advocate for saving your parents may be ethics of care, which focuses on the virtue of prioritising those who are close to you.

Ethical philosophies are designed to be general guidelines applicable to any moral question, so it makes no sense to ask which ethical philosophy applies to a specific case. They will all have something to say on it. To wit:

Utilitarianism will ask which action best serves public utility
Virtue ethics will ask which action most represents our ideal selves
Consequentialism will ask which of the action's (ongoing) outcomes are most desirable
Deontology will ask which action makes more sense as a universally applied law

No ethical philosophy will actually tell us which decision to make. The point of an ethical philosophy is to give us tools for making ethical decisions for ourselves, so people could reason their way to either answer in any system. This was, I think, the original point of the biblical story of Abraham and Isaac; Abraham was willing to sacrifice his own son to retain Yahweh's blessings on the community, but he could have easily justified preserving his son and letting the community suffer. Ethical philosophies aren't about what answer you get; they are about how you get to an answer.
